# 301 redirect from subdomain to domain using Plesk

Tags: redirect, subdomain, http-status-code-301, plesk

I had a subdomain m.example.com for mobile users, but recently I have redesigned my website to responsive one. so I don't need this subdomain. But Google has indexed many pages of this subdomain over the years and I don't wanna lose all that traffic. 
All I want to 301 redirect mobile traffic to main website. e.g.

**m.example.com to example.com**

**m.example.com/unique-link to example.com/unique-link**

I have **Windows Server 2012 R2** with **Plesk 12** running on it.
So far I have tried to learn from Plesk tutorials online but none of them worked for me, and I don't wanna use server redirect from my asp.net website.

Please refer me a guide or solution.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create domain alias m.example.com for domain example.com.

You just need to rename existed sub-domain m.example.com to avoid name clash.

[image: Plesk domain alias 301 HTTP redirect]

Comment: Yeah I have already done it. But it redirects to root Domain only not the inner pages. I want page to page redirection.

Comment: It's quite strange, I've just check that page to page redirect is working, May be there some other redirects or page doesn't exists?